# API_Key for authentication for Cloud Speech API

Tags: python, google-cloud-speech

I am using google speech api for python. I am trying to use API_key for authentication but it is not taking it. Has google dropped the API_keys as authentication?

Comment: can you add the error or what ever ` it is not taking it.` means

Answer (score 0):

In order to properly investigate and reproduce the issue you're currently experiencing, I would appreciate if you can share a snippet of your Python code along with the error message that has been triggered. Also, share with us which client library version of the Google Speech API you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find this public reference [https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys] stating that Google Cloud Speech API can be used with API Keys.